# Help a beginner with Mimic III

Tags: mimic-iii

I am a beginning user of the MIMIC III database, and I would like to query the database to get a list of all patients in Mimic III that have had a blood transfusion (ICD 9 code 9901 - 9905). Does anyone know of a tutorial that might help me do this query?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT(subject_id) FROM mimiciii.procedures_icd 
WHERE icd9_code IN ('9901','9902','9903','9904','9905')
ORDER BY subject_id